# How to get feature information from vector layer in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers

In case of `Openlayers 2` I am able to get feature information but how to get feature information from vector layer in `Openlayers 3`

below code how to extract information of the feature?

```
 var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function(extent) {
      $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          service: 'WFS',
          version: '1.1.0',
          request: 'GetFeature',
          typename: 'dgm:all_block_boundary_point',
          srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
          bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
        }
      }).done(function(response) {
        layerWFS
        .getSource()
        .addFeatures(new ol.format.WFS()
          .readFeatures(response));
         // console.log(response);
      });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
  })
}); 
map.addLayer(layerWFS);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Without looking at what you have tried, it will be hard for others to see what exactly your problem is. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to add some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the feature information using [`feature.getProperties()`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#getProperties) to get all properties or [`feature.get()`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#get) for a specific one.

**Edit**: Looks like he wants to retrieve the feature info by selection. Here's **OP**'s solution for it.

I have found solution by using `ol.interaction.Select()`

```
 var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select();
    map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);

    map.on('singleclick', function(event){  
layerWFS.getProperties();
        layerWFS.once('precompose',function(event){
          var selectedFeatures = selectSingleClick.getFeatures();

          readFeature(selectedFeatures);

        });
    });
    function readFeature(features){

       var myfeature = features.item(0);

        console.log(myfeature.get('block_name'));
        console.log(myfeature.get('latitude'));
        console.log(myfeature.get('longitude'));
    }
```

Comment: your solution is when user click on the layer. if we want attributes on layer load. i did something like that  var att = sourceWFS.getProperties();
     var attStr = att.state;
     alert(attStr);

Comment: but it does not return attributes